# parsing xml inside a node with Qt and Xquery

Tags: qt4.8, qxmlquery

I'm trying to parse the following  content with Qt4.8.

```
QString l_dynamicResult("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\
                  <u:BrowseResponse xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1\">\
                  <Result>&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/&quot; xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:upnp=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/&quot; xmlns:sec=&quot;http://www.sec.co.kr/&quot; xmlns:dlna=&quot;urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/&quot;&gt;&lt;container id=&quot;0/1&quot; parentID=&quot;0&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;Fichiers&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.container.storageFolder&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;/container&gt;&lt;container id=&quot;0/0&quot; parentID=&quot;0&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;TV&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.container.storageFolder&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;/container&gt;&lt;container id=&quot;0/5&quot; parentID=&quot;0&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;Flux RSS&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.container.storageFolder&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;/container&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;</Result>\
                  <NumberReturned>3</NumberReturned>\
                  <TotalMatches>3</TotalMatches>\
                  <UpdateID>0</UpdateID>\
                   </u:BrowseResponse>");
```

I'm able to display the content using the following code:

```
QByteArray l_array;
QBuffer l_buffer(&l_array);
l_buffer.setData(l_dynamicResult.toUtf8());
l_buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
l_info = "declare namespace xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';\
         declare namespace fn='http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions';\
      declare namespace dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1';\
let $result := fn:doc($xmlString)//Result/fn:string()  \
return ($result )                     ";
QStringList l_cdsContent;
l_q.bindVariable("xmlString", &l_buffer);
l_q.setQuery(l_info);
l_res = l_q.evaluateTo(&l_cdsContent);
Log("query res=")<<(l_res ?"Ok":"error");
qDebug()<<"l_cdsContent="<<l_cdsContent;
```

The output is:

```
l_cdsContent=<DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/" xmlns:sec="http://www.sec.co.kr/" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/"><container id="0/1" parentID="0" restricted="1"><dc:title>Fichiers</dc:title><upnp:class>object.container.storageFolder</upnp:class></container><container id="0/0" parentID="0" restricted="1"><dc:title>TV</dc:title><upnp:class>object.container.storageFolder</upnp:class></container><container id="0/5" parentID="0" restricted="1"><dc:title>Flux RSS</dc:title><upnp:class>object.container.storageFolder</upnp:class></container></DIDL-Lite>
```

To print , I tried to use:

```
 let $result := fn:doc($xmlString)//Result \
 let $title := $result//dc:title/fn:string()  \
 return ($title )
```

But the result is empty.

For now, the workaround would be to get `$result` to pass it to another QBuffer to apply the same process.

Did I miss something obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible to get the info in one pass because the default namespaces are different: The result requires `xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/"`.

For information, this is the second pass I use:

```
        QByteArray l_array1;
        QBuffer l_buffer1(&l_array1);
        QString l_xml(l_cdsContent.at(0));
        l_buffer1.setData(l_xml.toUtf8());
        l_buffer1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        l_info = "declare default element namespace 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite' ;\
            declare namespace fn='http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions';\
              declare namespace dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1';\
              declare namespace upnp='urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp';\
              declare namespace sec='http://www.sec.co.kr';\
              declare namespace dlna='urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0';\
              for $i in fn:doc($xmlString1)//node() \
                let $title := if (fn:compare(fn:name($i ), 'dc:title')=0) \
                              then $i/fn:string() \
                              else ()\
                let $id := if (fn:compare(fn:name($i ), 'container')=0) \
                              then $i/@id/fn:string() \
                            else () \
             return ($id, $title)\
              ";
        QXmlQuery l_q1;
        l_q1.bindVariable("xmlString1", &l_buffer1);
        l_q1.setQuery(l_info);
        QStringList l_result;
        l_res = l_q1.evaluateTo(&l_result);
        Log("query res=")<<(l_res ?"Ok":"error");
        qDebug()<<"l_result="<<l_result;
```